# building the interface of an eclipse plugin with JavaFX or HTML5?

Tags: html, eclipse-plugin, swt, javafx

I am looking for an alternative to swt for building the interface of an Eclipse plugin I want to develop.
Is it possible to build the interface of the plugin with JavaFX or HTML5 instead of swt ?.

I am targeting Eclipse Juno 4.2 or later.

Comment: To get info on using JavaFX as the UI for an Eclipse plugin, consider posting a question on the [e(fx)clipse forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/efxclipse).

Comment: What are the use cases for your plug-in? I.e. is it going to be distributed as part of an Eclipse RCP, or standalone?

Comment: hi @tkotisis, it is just a standalone plugin

Comment: @Sergio, what Eclipse versions are you targeting?

Comment: just updated the question with that info @tkotisis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse 4 defines an application model, i.e. a model of all the parts forming the application UI. The application model is decoupled from its presentation.

This means that different UI toolkits (SWT,XWT,JavaFX,etc.), can be used to implement the model. Theoretically you can build a UI using any presentation technology you want.

That said, Eclipse 4.2 (the IDE) still relies on good ol' SWT for it's UI. Which means, your plug-in will require some additional dependencies to be able to use a different toolkit.

[e(fx)clipse](http://efxclipse.org) (already mentioned by jewelsea), provides the necessary Eclipse tooling to build your plug-in. Among other things it plugs a [JavaFX ViewPart plug-in template](http://efxclipse.org/tut3.html), which creates an example plug-in and adds the necessary bundle dependencies for you.

Imho, this would be your best bet.

Comment: do you have any idea if Eclipse will eventually move to JavaFX instead of SWT ?. I have understood that it is possible to implement the plugin with JavaFX, but still I have not really got if it IS a good idea or not to use JavaFX for a new plugin. SWT is supposed to use a native look and feel, and as far as I know that is not the case for JavaFX. Does it mean that a plugin implemented with JavaFX could look weird ?

Comment: @Sergio, have no idea where Eclipse is headed.
JavaFX might look out of place for some types of applications, but there are certainly cases where this is not true. Heavily depends on your app and it's design.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of things going on, Eclipse versioning can be a bit confusing nowadays (at least for me), you can take a look at [E4](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4) but it is not widely used. It has the ability of desining UI with [Eclipse RCP/CSS](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/RCP/CSS).
An other posibility is [XWT](http://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/XWT). I've seen some business ready application using XWT so it seems to be mature enough. Even [WindowBuilder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) can be used to build UI with XWT. Which is actually declarative UI constructing with XML.
 If you want to have only the OSGi "goodies" you can take a look at [Apache Felix](http://felix.apache.org/site/index.html) or [Eclipse Virgo](http://www.eclipse.org/virgo/) (Spring-powered). They are application servers based on OSGi so you can build module based enterprise applications.
Last but not least if you are OK with SWT/JFace but want to have web application, take a look at [RAP](http://www.eclipse.org/rap/). I have seen a full RCP application converted to RAP running in a regular browser.